# Handling MemoryError when Training a Model on Large Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, out-of-memory, bigdata, training-data

I have a final processed dataset with shape (1217, 1230748), and it gives me errors like "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 11.2 GiB for an array with shape (1217, 1230748) and data type float64". I got the error with this code:

```
sklearn.set_config(transform_output='pandas')

make_column_transformer = partial(make_column_transformer, remainder='passthrough')
drop = make_column_transformer(('drop', ['CAMPAÑA', 'Fecha','Day', 'Month', 'Year']))
encoder = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), ['remainder__ID_FINCA', 'remainder__ID_ZONA', 'remainder__ID_ESTACION', 'remainder__modeWinddirectiondiscrete', 'remainder__Phase']))
preprocessing = make_pipeline(drop, encoder)

pipe = Pipeline([('preprocessing', preprocessing),('modelo', Ridge())])


parameters = {'modelo__alpha':np.logspace(-4, 4, 9, endpoint=True),
              'modelo__max_iter':[1000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 15000],
              'modelo__solver':['auto', 'svd', 'cholesky', 'lsqr', 'sparse_cg', 'sag', 'saga']}

search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = pipe, 
                            param_distributions=parameters, 
                            n_iter = 20,
                            cv=RepeatedKFold(n_splits = 5, n_repeats = 5, random_state = 0),
                            verbose = 1,
                            n_jobs = 4,
                            random_state = 0,
                            error_score='raise',
                            return_train_score = True)

search.fit(X_Train, y_Train)
print(search.best_params_, end='\n\n')

ridge = search.best_estimator_
description = 'Ridge regression'
show_results(description, ridge, X_Train, y_Train, X_Test, y_Test)
```

While training the model on this dataset, I encountered a MemoryError. Is there a way to train the model in chunks or any recommendations to solve this issue? I also attempted to transform the dataset from float64 to float32, but the problem persisted.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to handle this situation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please point me to what a "shape" is in this context.

Comment: @RickJames the shape is the number of columns and the number of rows of the dataset

Answer (score 0):

- 1.5 billion cells would take 12GB if each cell is a `float64` (8 bytes).
- Python, if it is like many other languages, has a lot of overhead for each cell.
- C and C++ would allocate only 8 bytes.
- Some other languages allocate about 40 bytes.